# Topology - find interior and boundary

Tags: general-topology

Question "Consider the set of the naturals N with the topology where the open sets are the empty set and the sets which their complementar is finite. Let A={n: n>=5} and B={1,2,3}. Find the interior of A and the boundary of B."

My try:
For the interior of A: well the interior of A are all the x in N such that there is a open set S, x is in S and S is contained in A.
I think int(A)=A but i dont know how to write it formally can somebody help?

For the boundary of B: I know that boundary(B)=all x in N such that all open sets S such that x is in S we have: the intersection of S and B and the intersection of S and the complementar of B are both non-empty....i know this is too obvious but i have no idea of how to start...can someone just give a hint of how to think? thanks!!!

Comment: Hint: A is an open set. What is the interior of of an open set?

Comment: Show that $B$ is closed and has empty interior. The boundary is the closure minus the interior.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is co-finite so it is open so it is its own interior.$B$ is closed because its complement is co-finite and therefore its complement is open.The space is $T_1$ (meaning one-element subsets are closed) but has no isolated points (meaning no one-element subset is open ). So for any finite subset $B$ and any $p\in B$ and any nbhd $U$ of $p$, the set $B\backslash \{p\}$ is closed $$\text {so } V=U\backslash (B\backslash \{p\}) \text { is open, and } p\in V\subset U.$$ So $V$, which is  infinite  , contains points not in $B$.Hence  any nbhd $U$ of $p$ intersects $N\backslash B$. In other words $$\text {any  }p\in B \text { belongs to } \overline {N\backslash B}.$$$$\text {Therefore } \partial B=\bar B\cap \overline {N\backslash B}=B\cap \overline {N\backslash B}\supset B.$$ On the other hand $B\supset\partial B$ because $B$ is closed. So $\partial B\supset B\supset \partial B$, whence $B=\partial B.$